# How to customize a UIActionSheet in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

If I want to make a UIActionSheet like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CDds.png), what’s the best practice?

1. Customize the default UIActionSheet.
   or
2. Create a UIView and add some controls to it, make it like a ActionSheet.

Maybe there are some other way to make it, thank you.

image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CDds.png

Comment: Ios8 uses UIAlertController. Completely customizable and more flexible then it's predecessor. It has built in handlers.

Comment: What is customized about the action sheet in your image? It looks like a standard action sheet.

Comment: @rmaddy But it's a little different, the backgroundColor and the textColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not add subviews to, or alter the layout of, the existing action sheet view. It is not yours to customize in that way.

Nor is there any need to do so. It is easy to write your own presented view controller that looks and acts like an action sheet (custom animation, dimming of the background, small size, and so forth). So if there is a real need for a customized action sheet, that is the proper approach.

So, of the two options you suggest, go for the second.

Comment: This is my proof-of-concept for an alert view; it doesn't answer your question for an action sheet, but it shows how easy the whole thing is. https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7/tree/master/CustomAlertViewDemo

Comment: This is not really an answer but a comment. The question asks how to customize. This simply states that it is easy to roll your own with no details of any kind.

Comment: @rmaddy the question does not ask how to customize. It asks which of two possible approaches is better, and I answered that.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov Thanks for the explanation. Quite helpful really. Sorry about that.

Comment: @matt it's ok, let's be kind. I removed my comments, you are an expert in this field and your current answer isn't lq anymore.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov No offense taken, and I apologize again. However, I would argue that my original answer was never low quality. Whether it got flagged by a robot or by a person, if you look at the _actual question asked_ — which you are supposed to do when considering the low-quality queue — I think my original answer was perfectly good, and the right response in the queue was, "No, it's fine."

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do a custom UI for the action sheet, best to build something using a custom solution (UIViews with tap gesture recognizers, UIControl subclass, UIButtons, etc). UIActionSheet/UIAlertController doesn't give you that fine grained control over the UI to do a pixel perfect recreation of the image you posted.